# Docker-compose does not see the new volume added in `docker-compose.yml`

Tags: docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` from which I started a couple of services. I add a new volume mapping to one of the services and then try to restart the container with

`docker compose restart <service_name>`

but the volume is still not mapped and not available from within the image.

What is the right way to add a volume to an image defined with docker compose?

Answer (score 3):

Oki, so it turns out that `restart` is just a refresh of the existing image but changes nothing in the parameters with which it is started.

In order to have compose take into account volume mapping changes in the docker-compose.yml file one has ro run:

`docker compose up --build <service_name>`

There might be other solutions, but this is what I ended up doing.